# How to make an entity accessible from two different entities JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Hi I am new to JPA and i would like to know if it is possible to map two entities to another entity?

For example lets say i have:

-entity1

```
public class LieuEnseignement implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "NO_ORGNS", nullable = false)
private Long noOrganisme;
@Column(name = "NO_ADR_GEOGR")
private Long noAdresseGeographique;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="etabEns", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<AdresseGeographique> adresseGeographique;
```

-entity 2

```
public class EtablissementEnseignement implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "NO_ORGNS", nullable = false)
private Long noOrganisme;
@Column(name="NO_ADR_GEOGR")
private Long noAdresseGeographique;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="etabEns", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<AdresseGeographique> adresseGeographique;
```

-entity 3

```
public class AdresseGeographique implements Serializable{
@Column(name="NO_ADR", nullable = false)
private Long noAdresse;
@Column(name="LIGNE1_ADR", nullable = false, length = 40)
private String ligne1AdrGeographique;
@Column(name="LIGNE2_ADR", nullable = false, length = 40)
private String ligne2AdrGeographique;
@Column(name="VILLE", nullable = false, length = 46)
private String villeAdrGeographique;
@Column(name="PROV_PAYS", nullable = false, length = 30)
private String provincePaysAdrGeographique;
@Column(name="CD_POSTAL", nullable = false, length = 6)
private String codePostaleAdrGeographique;
@Column(name="CD_MUNICIPALITE", nullable = false, length = 5)
private String codeMunicipaliteAdrGeographique;
@Column(name="POSTN_X", nullable = false)
private String positionXAdrGeographique;
@Column(name="POSTN_Y", nullable = false)
private String positionYAdrGeographique;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "NO_ADR", referencedColumnName = "NO_ADR_GEOGR", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private EtablissementEnseignement etabEns;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "NO_ADR", referencedColumnName = "NO_ADR_GEOGR", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private LieuEnseignement lieuEns;
```

So basically entity 1 and 2 call to entity 3 never at the same time. I thought i could just declare two seperate joincolumn but apparently this isn't possible.

edit1: As to why I did not use inheritance for entity 1 and 2 is because they are totally different but I did not put all the data contained within them as i did not find it relevent to the question.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Declaring two seperate JoinColumns should be totally possible. Of course they actually need to be seperate and not have the same column name as it currently is.

Comment: Should check inheritance as it seems LieuEnseignement  & EtablissementEnseignement  should inherit from one another or from a common entity. Plenty of exemple online : http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS the reason they have the same column name is because they way they are entity 1 and 2 which both have different tables contain the same column that both references the id column of entity 3